# Activity getting reset upon displaying an AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

My Activity is getting reset upon AlertDialog display.

I am learning Android and following this [tutorial.](http://androidtution5.blogspot.sg/2014/02/alertdialog-example-in-android.html)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Other Code
    submitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_button);
    // Other Code
    submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.setMessage("Hello " + name);
            alert.setTitle("Showing content in prompt window");
            alert.show();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
```

Here is my AlertDialogCode:

```
//creating the alert dialog
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setCancelable(true)
            .setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                //Action for close button
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
```

Activity gets reset as soon as the AlertDialog is displayed 
Can you help to tell the reason why the activity is getting reset?

Comment: Remove this line **setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);** from onclick method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `onCreate` method, you need to set content view just once. In your code you have already set the `setContentView` on the second line. If you happen to set it again, it will reset your activity and also remove your event handlers.

So suggest you to delete the second setContentView. This is also the problem in the tutorial you are following.

```
alert.show();
//setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // <-- Needs to be removed
```

Comment: Yes, after the alert dialog was closed my submit button was not doing anything.

Answer (score 2):

You are resetting the XML view of the activity with same layout so

Remove `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

```
 public void onClick(View v){
     AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
     alert.setMessage("Hello " + name);
     alert.setTitle("Showing content in prompt window");
     alert.show();
     //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ remove
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand the issue now.

Comment: @Supriya i am glad that i could help, happy coding

Answer (score 2):

Comment or remove the line

```
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

On you first code. Because this is forcing your activity to reload.

Comment: `forcing your app to reload` i guess by app you mean activity  or particularly , layout of activity